# A Summation Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20, c++-concepts

As the title mentioned, I am trying to implement a summation function which can deal with various type arbitrary nested iterable things in C++. The various type here includes the types that can be summed together, and the arbitrary nested iterable things here include for anything that has `begin()` and `end()`, such as `std::vector` and `std::array`.

```
template<typename T>
concept Summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

template<typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T x)
{
    x.begin();      // must have `x.begin()` 
    x.end();        // and `x.end()` 
};

template<typename T> requires Summable<T>
static T Sum(T inputNumber);        //  Deal with the base case like "Sum(static_cast<int>(1))"

template<class T> requires Iterable<T>
static auto Sum(const T& numbers);  //  Deal with the iterable case like "Sum(std::vector<long double>{ 1, 1, 1 })"


template<class T> requires Summable<T>
static inline T Sum(T inputNumber)
{
    return inputNumber;
}

template<class T>  requires Iterable<T>
static inline auto Sum(const T& numbers)
{
    long double sumResult = 0.0;
    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        sumResult = sumResult + Sum(element);
    }
    return sumResult;
}
```

The test cases are listed as below.

```
long double testNumber = 1;
    
std::vector<decltype(testNumber)> testVector1;
testVector1.push_back(testNumber);
testVector1.push_back(testNumber);
testVector1.push_back(testNumber);
std::cout << Sum(testVector1) << std::endl;

std::vector<decltype(testVector1)> testVector2;
testVector2.push_back(testVector1);
testVector2.push_back(testVector1);
testVector2.push_back(testVector1);
std::cout << Sum(testVector2) << std::endl;

std::vector<decltype(testVector2)> testVector3;
testVector3.push_back(testVector2);
testVector3.push_back(testVector2);
testVector3.push_back(testVector2);
std::cout << Sum(testVector3) << std::endl;

//  std::array test case
std::array<long double, 90> numberArray;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 90; i++)
{
    numberArray[i] = 1;
}
std::cout << std::to_string(Sum(numberArray)) + "\n";
```

However, there are some defects in the above `Sum` function

1. The type of return value in the implementation for the iterable case is always `long double`. It seems that this return type should be as same as the input iterable value type.
2. When it comes to the type `std::complex` which is not a built-in numeric types, this `sum` function can't work.

I tried to modified the `Sum` function into the following version.

```
template<class T>  requires Iterable<T>
static inline auto Sum(const T& numbers)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type sumResult = 0.0;     //  Update "long double" into "typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type"
    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        sumResult = sumResult + Sum(element);
    }
    return sumResult;
}
```

Then, it works well in `std::vector<>` case. However, the `typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type` can not handle the multi-nested iterable case, such as `std::vector<std::vector<std::complex>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex>>>`. Is there any possible solution to this problem?

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to be smarter in deriving the type of `sumResult`:

```
template<class T>  requires Iterable<T>
static inline auto Sum(const T& numbers)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::value_type
        value_type;

    decltype(Sum(std::declval<value_type &&>())) sumResult{};

    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        sumResult = sumResult + Sum(element);
    }
    return sumResult;
}
```

With this change, the shown code compiles with

```
std::complex<double> testNumber{1,0};
```

and also compiles the calculation involving a

```
std::array<std::complex<double>, 90> numberArray;
```

however there is no suitable overload for `std::to_string` taking a `std::complex` argument, so that part fails.